# INVALID_ARGUMENT exception when requesting Google's knowledge graph API

Tags: api

I've read the documentation on Google's knowledge graph and from what I understand we can search for results both based on a query and based on IDs. For getting results by a query, no problem whatsoever, but when I try to retrieve them by IDs, it fails. Setting aside what query I used myself, this is the request URL I got from Google's API Explorer:

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?ids=kg%3A%2Fm%2F01nrz4&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and the result is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

And I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the `ids` parameter. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's the thing. Each found instance has an attribute like this: `"@id": "kg:/m/0gkg6"` . So in this instance the id is `kg:/m/0gkg6`, but when we want to run a query based on ID, we should omit the `kg:` part.